# How to render django formset in a grid layout

Tags: django, django-templates

I have the following forms that will display several forms from a formset.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" style="margin-left: 40px; margin-right: 40px">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ formset.management_form }}
            {{ formset.non_form_errors }}
            {% for forma in formset.forms %}
                {{ forma }}
            {% endfor %}
<input class="btn bg-success" type="submit" value="Update" />
```

When I use this layout all the forms in the formset are displayed vertically:

Form 1
Form 2
Form 3
Form 4
...
...
...
Form n

Instead of have the forms laid out vertically, I would something like this:

Form 1         Form 2          Form 3
Form 4         ...             ...
Form n

ie there should be a max of 3 forms in each row.